# Errors after command "Mount-SPContentDatabase"

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, migration, content-migration

I'm migrating from version 2010 to version 2013, on command "**Test-SPContentDatabase**" it was possible to correct and establish all solutions, However, after command "**Mount-SPContentDatabase**", there were errors, please tell me how to fix it:

> Could not find Content Type 0x0101009148F5A04DDD49CBA7127AADA5FB792B00AADE34325A8B49CDA8BB4DB53328F214.
>
> Failed to set content types on list SiteCollectionImages
>
> Exception: Failed to set the content type "Image" or "Asset" in the
>   SiteCollectionImages list
>      in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.AssetLibrary.LogError(SPLog log, String format, Exception e, Object[] args)     in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.AssetLibrary.UpgradeDocumentLibrary(SPDocumentLibrary docLib, Boolean addViews, Boolean accessFileStreams, SPLog log)     in Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.Internal.Upgrade.CmsVersionToVersionImageLibraryUpgradeAction.UpgradePublishingSite(SPSite site)
>
> Upgrade [SPSite Url=http://servername:3000/sites/test] failed. Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Upgrade.MossSiteSequence has the ContinueOnFailiure bit set. Moving on to the next object in sequence.
>
> Exception: Action 13.0.16.0 of Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Upgrade.MossSiteSequence failed.

And Error web application, moved Visualization:

[image]

**Edit**

```
Results after Repair-SPsite:{

SPSiteHealthResult Status=Passed RuleName="Conflicting Content Types" RuleId=befe203b-a8c0-48c2-b5f0-27c10f9e1622,

SPSiteHealthResult Status=FailedWarning RuleName="Customizable files" RuleId=cd839b0d-9707-4950-8fac-f306cb920f6c,

SPSiteHealthResult Status=Passed RuleName="Lack of collections" RuleId=ee967197-ccbe-4c00-88e4-e6fab81145e1,

SPSiteHealthResult Status=Passed RuleName="Missing Parent Content Types" RuleId=a9a6769f-7289-4b9f-ae7f-5db4b997d284...}

PassedCount : 6 FailedWarningCount : 1 FailedErrorCount : 0
```

Comment: You could try run powershell on the site collection that returned an error. Repair-SPsite http://servername:3000/sites/test]

Comment: Results after **Repair-SPsite**:{ SPSiteHealthResult Status=Passed RuleName="Conflicting Content Types" RuleId=befe203b-a8c0-48c2-b5f0-27c10f9e1622, SPSiteHealthResult Status=FailedWarning RuleName="Customizable files" RuleId=cd839b0d-9707-4950-8fac-f306cb920f6c, SPSiteHealthResult Status=Passed RuleName="Lack of collections" RuleId=ee967197-ccbe-4c00-88e4-e6fab81145e1, SPSiteHealthResult Status=Passed RuleName="Missing Parent Content Types" RuleId=a9a6769f-7289-4b9f-ae7f-5db4b997d284...} PassedCount : 6
FailedWarningCount : 1
FailedErrorCount : 0

Comment: Conflicting content types.. are the site accessible? Did you have any solutions in your 2010 farm enabled?

Comment: Conflicting content types.. are the site accessible? How to check and to fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $url = 'http://servername:3000/sites/test'
>   Disable-SPFeature -Identity publishingSite -url $url -force

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, one site http://servername:3000/sites/test cannot be upgraded successfully.

You could run the PowerShell command below in SharePoint 2010. After that, upgrade the site to SharePoint 2013.

```
stsadm.exe -o localupgradestatus
```

There is a similar post:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/8c5731cb-478e-4fb2-887b-514dd0cdecc3/sharepoint-2013-site-collection-upgrade-completed-with-errors-any-suggestion?forum=sharepointadmin